# HTTP POST vs PUT large file transfer

Tags: http, post, put

I'm using HTTP requests(on the sender side) for a single large file transfer(20gb) and  the receiving side is a remote system which just receives the file. Im coding in C++ on linux using libcurl on the sender side and mongoose webserver on the receiving side.Will there be actually be any difference in the performance(speed-wise maybe)?

I've read about this in a few places but I dont quite understand the exact difference so please if someone can explain it in simple words it would be really great. Thanks

Comment: What difference do you think there will be, other than the HTTP verb?

Comment: Is it good idea to upload such a big file with HTTP???

Comment: I started my programming with basic tcp sockets, then i wanted to try including some other application layer protocol too.. just a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in performance, however if you are letting the user specify the path of the file, you should use PUT, and if you know where the file is going in the system, use POST for idomatic code. But no, there is no performance benefits of one over the other.

Comment: Yes it is the user specifying the file address but again can you explain little more why that would make a diff?

Comment: Well, PUT is exclusively for *file* transfers, whereas POST can be for any kind of data stream.

Comment: @HaloWebMaster, that's not correct You can use PUT and POST for any type of data.   There are a lot of REST APIs receiving JSON in PUT requests to update objects for example.